# Introducing Tetronogram - Beginner's Version

Tags: word, grid-deduction, polyomino, nonogram

### Introducing Tetronogram! <sub>(named by @MrPie)</sub>

> - The puzzle is made of a grid like a nonogram.
> - Notations are along the axes like a classic nonogram but numbers are replaced by the names of the tetromino.
> - The names are I, L, T, O, and S.
> - The tetrominoes can be flipped and rotated, therefore a J/Z tile would have the L/S notation.
> - A notation of ‘L’ means there is a part of the L tile on that row or column. It can be 1 tile, 2 tiles, or 3. Same theory for other tiles.
> - Most steps can be deduced by logic alone. There are 16 possible solutions (I have play tested it myself :D ), but only one make sense.
> - Not all grids have to be filled.
> - Different from other nonograms, there need not be a space between two tetrominoes.

[image]

Since this is a new genre of puzzle, it is highly encouraged that you explain your logic flow as you answer. Happy puzzling :)

Comment: I am just going to point our that this particular puzzle breaks a golden rule of nonograms in that there must be a space between similar elements (right hand columns have LL).

Comment: @Perry edited accordingly, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is this

> [image]
>  which spells "HUE" in the middle of the picture.

Explaining $16$ possible solutions

> Here is what we can logically deduce from the clues provided.
>  [image]
>  The two Ts in the top of the picture can both have two orientations (can be inverted). The L in the upper right corner can have any one of the four orientations which allow it to fit in the $2 \times 3$ box in the upper right hand corner. $2 \times 2 \times 4 = 16$ so the counting matches. We can see that the picture almost spells out HUE already, in white, so we can make the selections to make this shape more concrete.

Some notes on how the solution is obtained.

> First notice that there is a horizontal space between each instance of I in the columns. This means all Is that appear are vertical in orientation.
>  A quick examination of the O and S allows us to place those two precisely.
>  After that, it's not too difficult to discover that all Ts are in a $2 \times 3$ orientation (up or down) and we can fit in the Ls around them.

Comment: yeah, you're right, that's my fault. the first one to get the explanation gets the check!

Comment: Username checks out.